# Apex JSON parsing error

Tags: json, apex-code

I am getting the following error in my code:

> System.JSONException null Don't know the type of the Apex object to
>   deserialize at [line:1, column:1] 11 (System Code)
>   Class.FactorLab.FactorLabWebservices.RetrieveUsersFromFactorLab: line
>   60, column 1 Class.FactorLab.PullUsers.execute: line 61, column 1

Here is the code in question:

```
public static List<FactorLabPullUser> RetrieveUsersFromFactorLab(List<String> ids){ 
    HttpRequest req = getHttpRequest(baseUrl + '/ws/sfdc/people/retrieve', 'POST');        
    req.setBody(JSON.serialize(ids));
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    if(Test.isRunningTest()){
        return null;
    }        
    HttpResponse res = sendRequest(req);
    // This is the line with the error
    List<FactorLabPullUser> flusers = (List<FactorLabPullUser>)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), Type.forname('List<FactorLabPullUser>')); 

    return flusers;
}
```

I'm sure that it's receiving valid JSON, but I'm not sure the exact JSON it's receiving when it gets this error.  It could simply get an empty array:

```
[]
```

It could also get something like this:

```
[ { "SFDCStatus" : "RETRIEVED",
    "address" : "123 Fake St.",
    "addressLine1" : "Address1",
    "addressLine2" : "Address2",
    "city" : "San Francisco",
    "companyName" : "Big Cheese, Inc.",
    "deleted" : false,
    "email" : "james.willard@fake.com",
    "firstName" : "James",
    "hireDate" : "2000-04-15T00:00:00Z",
    "id" : 39,
    "lastName" : "Willard",
    "lastUpdated" : "2011-11-23T05:44:03Z",
    "myersBriggs" : "SFDC",
    "name" : "James Willard",
    "phone" : "415-555-1212",
    "position" : "Big Chief",
    "regions" : [ { "deleted" : false,
          "id" : 445,
          "name" : "Mountain"
        } ],
    "state" : "CA",
    "yearsExp" : 20.0,
    "zip" : "94131"
  },
  { "SFDCStatus" : "RETRIEVED",
    "deleted" : false,
    "firstName" : "Daniel",
    "id" : 40,
    "lastName" : "Adams",
    "lastUpdated" : "2011-11-23T05:44:03Z",
    "name" : "Daniel Adams"
  }
]
```

Any ideas? Someone told me this was a Salesforce.com bug, but it seems like even if that were true, there must be a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you *may* not be casting properly. I haven't played around with the serialize/deserialize native JSON much yet and have preferred to do my own parsing/persisting. But your line causing the error looks suspicious:

```
List<FactorLabPullUser> flusers = (List<FactorLabPullUser>)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), Type.forname('List<FactorLabPullUser>'));
```

I think it should look like the following:

```
List<FactorLabPullUser> flusers = (List<FactorLabPullUser>)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), List<FactorLabPullUser>.class);
```

Comment: That worked, but according to the original author of the code, that will only work for a little while and then start getting the same error again until you switch it back to the original way.  Some sort of "caching" issue.  It doesn't make any sense to me.  Does that make any sense to you?

Comment: A caching issue sounds like something that calls for a new case to be submitted, if it's actually true, since the code I modeled this after is straight from the Apex developer's guide. In other words, if true, it's a Salesforce bug and will be fixed. But personally I've stuck with hand-parsing and it's been fantastic once I figured out the nuances of the system JSON parser class/methods. Just the current restrictions of the serialize/deserialize features alone are enough to give me the creeps. 2-cents.

Comment: I submitted a case, but they rejected it as I am not have premier support.  I understand having to pay for support, but not really to pay to submit a bug.  Oh well.  So when you say "hand-parsing" you are not talking about writing your own JSON parser in Apex are you?

Comment: No, not my own JSON parser. I use System.JSONParser to walk through JSON results and populate my custom objects myself. Look at the sample code for the consumeObject method here: http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2011/09/hands-on-with-the-new-native-json-parser.html. Basically I use JSONParser to walk the JSON and locate the data elements I'm interested in. It's more work than simply deserializing JSON, but I'm more in control and don't have the same restrictions. If you have a Map<SObject, List<SObject>, for example, you can't serialize it properly. Only String-SObject.

Comment: I just ran into this issue as well, getting declined support through our partner portal (relating to suspected Salesforce bug posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352149/exceeded-id-limit-emptyrecyclebin-id-limit-reached-200/9353413#9353413). Yes, for quality's sake I hope they publish a way for everyone to report potential Salesforce bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see for sure from your code snippit but if the FactorLabPullUser class is an inner class you will need to fully qualify it for `Type.forName()` to work.

I would expect to see something like this:

```
List<FactorLabPullUser> flusers = (List<FactorLabPullUser>)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), Type.forname('List<Outerclass.FactorLabPullUser>'));
```

I think that the bug you mention is to do with the use of the `.class` method - I have noticed this not always return a valid `Type`.